# How to update location in CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I am working on map application and when i run the app it shows my current location and getting the right latitude and longitude , have to send the information to someone through mail, I have implemented all the things and till the mail is send is working fine, i only need help regarding updating CLLocationManager function, after sending the mail, i have tried to call the function [locationmanager startupdatinglocation] however it got get called for the second time, even i have put NSTimer to ask for the location for second time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try like this place,

```
 locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 locationManager.delegate = self;
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(UpdateLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

In viewdidload and call this method from timer,

```
-(void)UpdateLocation
{
   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the information i was doing the same thing previously which you have mentioned however didn't add locationmanager.delegate = self for second time,i am checking it right now and thanks for the information.

Comment: doing `locationManager.delegate = self` in a timer triggered method should be redundant.

Comment: This is just bad. You shouldn't set the delegate repeatedly and starting over and over from a timer.

Comment: you call [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
then  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
to refesh GPS 
link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation?language=objc